# Hide <sidebar> if subpages are shown

Tags: pages

I have this code to show subpages in everypage.

```
<?php $parent = $post->ID; ?> 

<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=15&post_type=page&post_parent='.$parent);
 while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>

<?php $image_thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image-thumb', true); ?>
<div class="subpages">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


<?php
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
?>
<div class="subpages-img" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) no-repeat center !important; height: 400px; width: 150px;">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Can I somehow do the following: If this code is used/there are subpages in a page then dont show sidebar, if there are no subpages, then show sidebar?

Comment: [DON'T USE `query_posts`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) function!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like you are using an if-statement for showing the sub-pages? If you are not, I guess you can do it with jQuery.

```
var sub = $("div.subpages");

if (sub.length > 0) {
    $("#secondary").hide(); // replace "secondary" with the ID of the sidebar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the child pages as an array

```
// Get an array of child pages.
$child_pages = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'post_type'      => page,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
) );
```

Then check `$child_pages` to see if it has anything in it.

```
if ( $child_pages )
    show_child_pages( $child_pages );

else
    get_sidebar();
```

Then write a user function to show the child pages.

```
/**
 * Show page subpages.
 *
 * @param array $child_pages An array of post objects.
 */
function show_child_pages( array $child_pages ) {

    $sub_page_format = '
        <div class="subpages">
            <h2><a href="%s">%s</a></h2>
            <div class="subpages-img" style="background: url(%s) no-repeat center !important; height: 400px; width: 150px;">
            %s
            </div>
        </div>
    ';

    foreach ( $child_pages as $post ) {

        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array( 5600, 1000 ), false, '' );

        printf(
            $sub_page_format,
            get_permalink( $post->ID ),
            get_the_title( $post->ID ),
            $src[0],
            get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )
        );
    }
}
```

If you prefer to use [Template Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/) like you were doing it, use this:

```
/**
 * Show page subpages.
 *
 * @param array $child_pages An array of post objects.
 */
function show_child_pages( array $child_pages ) {
    global $post;

    foreach ( $child_pages as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );

        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
        $image_thumb = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image-thumb', true );
    ?>

        <div class="subpages">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div class="subpages-img" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) no-repeat center !important; height: 400px; width: 150px;">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: sorry, my fault... was a bit tired :)